# Ant hills replaced dead grass

Tags: grass, weed-control, ants

I used a general purpose weed killer to kill off clumps of grass in my driveway. Now all of those dead clumps of grass have been replaced by tons of ant hills. What’s going on? Do I need to be concerned?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ants are probably taking advantage of the space in the soil that used to be occupied by the (now dead and shriveling) roots of the weeds you killed. Unless the ants are causing a problem, I wouldn't worry about them.